# android Bitmap resize and compress file image not found after camera

Tags: java, android, bitmap, camera

i have a camera take picture method, it will intent to camera like this :

```
public void takePicture() {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

        cameraHelper = new CameraHelper();
        cameraHelper.initialize(this, this.getApplicationContext(), CAPTURED_IMAGE_PATH);
        Intent imageIntent = cameraHelper.dispatchTakePictureIntent(CameraHelper.ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B);


        startActivityForResult(imageIntent, CameraHelper.ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B);

    }
```

after user finish take and save photo, i try to get the result and resize & compress it.
this is my on acitivty result :

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


        if (requestCode == CameraHelper.ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B || requestCode == CameraHelper.ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_S) {

            File f = cameraHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (f != null) {

                try{
                    Log.i("PHOTO", "Start to resize");
                    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets().open(f.getAbsolutePath()));
                    Log.i("PHOTO", "orginal width : "+b.getWidth()+", original height : "+b.getHeight());
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, b.getWidth()/2, b.getHeight()/2, true);
                    Log.i("PHOTO", "Resize width : "+resized.getWidth()+", Resize height : "+resized.getHeight());
                    resized.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                    Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
                    Log.i("PHOTO", "Compress width : "+decoded.getWidth()+", Compress height : "+decoded.getHeight());

                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.i("PHOTO", e.toString());
                }


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "F IS NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }
```

but :(
there is error , and this is the log :

```
07-30 13:57:01.149: I/PHOTO(28841): Start to resize
07-30 13:57:01.154: I/PHOTO(28841): java.io.FileNotFoundException: file://storage/sdcard0/Pictures/imotax/capture/spop/IMG_20130730_135655_98370721.jpg
```

please help me.. 
to fix this and also it can resize and compress the image.
thanks guys

Comment: Did you check whether the file exists?

Comment: Here is the similar question can  help you. [Using android camera intent, getting uri, and then using uri](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122491/using-android-camera-intent-getting-uri-and-then-using-uri)

Comment: It's probably a path issue, check where the file is stored and correct that.

Comment: @g00dy hmm i use absolute path, i think it didn't wrong,

Comment: @FD_ fortunately file is exist